# How do I make an Angular2 application update instantly on all connected devices as the events are fired?

Tags: http, angular, ionic2

I need to build a restaurant management mobile application with Angular2 and Ionic2 and a website for the same restaurant with Angular2 that constantly make http connections to store and retrieve data from the database in order to maintain the latest data.

For example, If an order request was fired from a waiter's mobile phone, the new order is posted to the database, which I can accomplish.  the chef needs to get the instant notification that a new order has been created. Also, the data needs to be reflected in other employees' phones and also on the website.

All I can come up with is the use of `setInterval`, but since I've never done anything like this before, I'm not sure if this is the correct way.

**`component`**

```
orders: Order[];

constructor(private orderService: OrderService) {
  setInterval(function() {
    this.orderService
      .getOrders()
      .subscribe(
      (orders: Order[]) => this.orders = orders,
      (error: Response) => console.log(error)
  )}, 3000);
}

placeanOrder(order) {
  this.orderService.postOrder(order);
}
```

**`service`**

```
getOrders() Observable<any>{
  this.http.get(...).map(...);
}

placeOrder(order) {
  this.http.post(...).map(...);
}
```

When I try something like this, I get the same error logged to the console every second.

> Cannot read property 'getOrders' of undefined

1. Why am I getting the error?
2. How would I convert the Observable json data retrieved from server into my interface data type, in this case, of type `Order`?
3. What is a better approach to this?

Comment: No property is specified.

Comment: you can use websockets...

Comment: It is either polling API (what you're doing now) or using Websockets to push the updates from server side (which is more preferable).

Comment: Thanks. I will look into Websockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Cause wrong usage of callbacks! You have to use the arrow-syntax!

   - wrong: `setInterval(function() {`
   - right: `setInterval(() => {`
2. Just describe your function with correct types:

```js
getOrders(): Observable<Order[]> {
```

Nothing else needed. Property-names needs to be the same (interface/json)!

3. It's ok to use a timer. "Better" could be a never-closed-connection to the server, so server could SEND you that data and client don't have to POLL.

   - https://www.websocket.org/
   - http://socket.io/

Comment: Good info. Thanks.